# How to intercept button click, run analytics code, and then continue with click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intercept

I have been asked to build code where I can intercept the click of a button, stop the function that fires on the click, run an analytics script, then fire the original click function.  I can do this with JS/jQuery on a standard button when using onClick, but this button is built in Angular and using an ng-click instead, so I am a little out of my element.

The button I am trying to intercept is this:

```
<input id="btn-hero-form-try" class="btn btn-solid" data-ng-disabled="trialForm.buttonDisabled" data-ng-click="trialForm.submitTrialForm('personal')" type="submit" value="Download Free Trial">
```

A few things make this more difficult:  I have no access to the HTML code on the CMS, so I can't add any additional parameters that way, and have been asked not to inject any via script from the page.

I have been playing with the [ng-click-interceptor](https://github.com/magikMaker/ng-click-interceptor), but have not gotten it to work yet.

Any help, or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you modify `submitTrialForm` to execute the analytics code first?

Comment: I can make no changes to any of the page code, or corresponding functions.  That was my first question internally.  I already have the analytics code in a separate function, but altering the `submitTrialForm` function is not going to be possible.

Comment: Now I'm not sure what CAN you change...

Comment: So, with a normal button using onClick, I can watch for the onClick to be triggered, stop the function call, store the function for later use, fire my code, then trigger an artificial click to run that function (or run it directly).  Unfortunately, this doesn't work with ng-click as opposed to onClick.  This is where I was hoping for some help...

Comment: If I ask them to add something, or allow me to inject something, that will cause delays and issues higher up the chain, which I would like to avoid...At this point, is there any way to do what I described in my last comment without making changes/additions to the link?

Comment: I see, tough situation. Going outside the box - can you maybe run the analytics code on the server that handles the form request?

Comment: @Shomz Unfortunately not.  They don't want to change anything on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to upgrade common directive ngClick - just create your own!

In common words - they share same event but called separately.

It will not affect default, it will be called later so you need to mess with priority, and you will be needed to append it to existing application.

If you are aware of changing existing code - then you need jQuery, selector like [ngClick] to find any clickable item and run asynchronous .on(click) events depending on target content or value of ngClick attribute.

I don't think to sync analytics with callbacks of actual clicks is good idea, due to possible side effects on any step.

Comment: Agreed, but it's what I have to work with.  So, the final code will basically copy the original function out of the data-ng-click, insert my function name instead (on page load), then my function will fire on click, run the analytics and then run the original function, either once a 200 response is received, or after a 1 second delay, whichever comes first.  Not pretty, but it should do what they want.

Thanks for the help...

Comment: I guess you will use prevent default or propagation to prevent angular from handling it and just after your analitics done - unbind your own watcher for button, click on it again to actually do job that was supposed to be done

Comment: I don't think you can freely copy fn coz it is within angular structure but not within global application context

Comment: You need to eval function within scope where that click is defined, so or you should have it in global or just query their execution with prevents

Comment: Yeah, not going to be as easy as I originally hoped.

Comment: So, I tried stopping propagation using "data-ng-click="trialForm.submitTrialForm('personal');$event.stopPropagation();", just to see if it worked, but the event still fired.  I then tried completely removing the data-ng-click from the button and it still fired.  I've been scouring sites that provide some code, but little explanation of what the pieces do (more geared toward those already using Angularjs).

Comment: You forgot your own idea with onClick event dude

Comment: I thought you are not allowed to edit application but you telling me that you tried to stop propagation of ng click. Did you do that in existing code?

Comment: I did that from a console with the code I mentioned above.  No, I haven't touched the code itself.  What I tried was this: https://github.com/magikMaker/ng-click-interceptor